# Display one category on the shop page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So thats the question: how do I display only one category on the shop main page in woocommerce?

Comment: Have you tried ? Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it It should only display products from 'knives' category change it to your category.

Resource :- [Exclude a specific category from shop page](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/)

```
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

    function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

        if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
        if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

        if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

            $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'knives' ), // Display products in the knives category on the shop page
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )));

        }

        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows only one category's data:-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'storefront_post_header_categories', 6 );  
function storefront_post_header_categories() {  
global $product;  
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );  
if ($terms[0]->slug=='australian-open'){  
 dynamic_sidebar('accompanied-service');  
 }  
}
```